# comments not showing up - facebook comment box

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I simply tried this -

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-width="700" data-numposts="5" href="https://ec2-52-74-60-140.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/" > </div>
```

it shows the comment box but none of the comments are displayed if I comment something on it!

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a simple network communication error. My AWS instance was not being able to call the FB APIs properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=[your appid];
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Do you have this in your code?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/